# Mixed effect models for survival analysis

Tags: mixed-model, survival, multilevel-analysis

When performing survival analysis with mixed models I've usually used random intercept or random intercept and random slopes models with these codes in R:

Random intercept:

```
coxme(surv~variable1+ (1|grouping))
```

Random intercept and slope:

```
coxme(surv~variable1 + (1+ variable1|grouping))
```

With variable1 being a categorical dummy variable (1,0) and grouping variable being a nominal categorical variable (from 1 to x without order).

However, a colleague of mine told me that these models are not correct to perform these analyses as they do not assume a variable effect for each group, and told me to use this model that sound odd to me, as it removes the intercept:

```
coxme(surv~0+variable1+(variable1-1|grouping))
```

How should I interpret this code, as it looks like a pure random slope without intercept?

Comment: Is `variable1` categorical (factor) or continuous?

Comment: Categorical, more specifically is a binary variable, while groping is a nominal categorical variables (no order assumed). I edited the original question to be clear for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cox model does not fit an intercept parameter, see for example [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147160/modelling-proportional-hazards-in-cox-model-using-coxph-in-r) for some discussion. Therefore, fitting `surv ~ variable1` or `surv ~ 0 + variable1` will produce exactly the same parameters. `coxme` calls the default `coxph.fit` method if you don't have time-dependent covariates, so the behaviour will be the same as the fixed effects-only `coxph`.

```
library(survival)
data(cancer)
fit1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ celltype, data=veteran)
## Explicitly 'remove' intercept
fit2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 0+celltype, data=veteran)

## Notice how *only the formula* (call) differs
all.equal(fit1, fit2)
> "Component “terms”: formulas differ in contents"
> "Component “formula”: formulas differ in contents"            
> "Component “call”: target, current do not match when deparsed"
```

For your random effect, it is not really accurate to call a categorical/dummy covariate a 'slope' - this is usually the term used for a continuous variable that has a linear effect over its range. However, it turns out this is how `coxme` was implemented in that it only accepts a single *numeric* effect besides an intercept in the random effect specification. You are actually trying to fit multiple random **intercepts**, which might lead to some undesirable side effects.

The first specification, `(1 + variable1 | grouping)`, will fit an overall intercept and a 'slope' which is really just an intercept in the non-reference level of `variable1`. I'm not going to pretend I know much about the fitting algorithm inside `coxme` but I would *assume* that this produces roughly the same result as if you were fitting a separate intercept to each level of `variable1` (which the package does not allow directly). Compare this to how removing an intercept from a standard linear model changes the interpretation of categorical predictors from differences vs. reference to the mean in each category.

The second specification, `(variable1 | grouping)`, will fit only a random 'slope', which in your case becomes an intercept *for the non-reference level only*. This is not only a much less flexible structure, I'm quite sure that this is not what you want if your goal is to "assume a variable effect for each group" (where I'm taking "group" to mean "levels of `variable1`", because all models will produce separate random effects across all levels of `grouping` regardless).

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification! So, if I understand right, using (variable 1- 1|grouping) would give me an unreliable effect, as we are not checking the so called "fragility", right?

Comment: You still have a random effect, but I'm *quite* sure it's being fit on observations where `variable1` = 1 (or $\ne 0$) only.

Comment: Many thanks, you've been cristal clear.